# Links on FAQ page aren't working

Tags: plugins

I apologize if this is a naive question. I'm a Ruby on Rails developer and I'm not yet very comfortable with WordPress.

I built a WP site featuring an FAQ page using [Q and A Focus Plus FAQ plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/q-and-a-focus-plus-faq/). It works just fine except none of the links on the FAQ page, despite having valid `href` attributes, actually work. You can see what I'm talking about if you [visit my site](http://wp.snipsalonsoftware.com/faqs/).

I don't really know where to begin trying to debug such a funky problem. It of course seems like it should just work out of the box. Any advice?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am not sure I am seeing the problem you describe?

Comment: Yeah. I click on each individual FAQ link and nothing happens. I don't go to /# and I don't go to a different page. The URL stays the same. I don't get an error in the console. Just nothing.

Comment: I found a clue: when I disable JavaScript in Chrome, the links work. So there's some JavaScript somehow making these links not work.

Comment: I don't see any individual FAQ links at all, just the one main FAQ link. Ok. I take that back. The page is very different on some browsers... definitely Javascript related.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The FAQ plugin was intentionally "return false"-ing links on the page with a certain class, resulting in (intentional) silent failure. I removed that line of JS from the plugin and now the links work.

Comment: If you edited the plugin code itself, it will be overwritten when the plugin updates (which is always recommended). You might be better off changing the class or maybe bringing up this issue on their support forums for the developer to see.